# Can you detect a specific DLLand function load using ETW?

Tags: windows, powershell, dll, etw, logman

Is it possible to monitor calls to specific DLL functions in ETW?
I am still new to ETW, so is there any good site or procedure that might be helpful to me?

It would be great to be able to run it from powershell using the logman command.

Sorry for the messy question. But I am in trouble....
Thanks for reading.

I am now looking into whether this might work.

```
> logman query providers "{22FB2CD6-0E7B-422B-A0C7-2FAD1FD0E716}"

providers                                GUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process         {22FB2CD6-0E7B-422B-A0C7-2FAD1FD0E716}

値                   キーワード                説明
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x0000000000000010  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_PROCESS
0x0000000000000020  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_THREAD
0x0000000000000040  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_IMAGE
0x0000000000000080  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_CPU_PRIORITY
0x0000000000000100  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_OTHER_PRIORITY
0x0000000000000200  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_PROCESS_FREEZE
0x0000000000000400  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_JOB
0x0000000000000800  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_ENABLE_PROCESS_TRACING_CALLBACKS
0x0000000000001000  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_JOB_IO
0x0000000000002000  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_WORK_ON_BEHALF
0x0000000000004000  WINEVENT_KEYWORD_JOB_SILO
0x8000000000000000  Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process/Analytic
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: DLL calls are indirected through the import table. There is nothing between the caller and the callee.